# styling `TextValidator` in react-material-ui-form-validator

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-material-ui-form-validator` in my react form for material design as well as for validation, now i want to change the color of shrink label but not able to find any option to styling `TextValidator`, React material provide option to add class when label is shrink but not this. Any idea how I can use material design with the easy validation in react

this is the package that I am using

https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-material-ui-form-validator

Comment: Can I see some of your code, because I followed their example, but I do not see the validators checking the fields

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't have that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by applying styling with the data-attribute